# c# nested arrays of structures initialization

Tags: c#, struct, xml-deserialization

I am trying to build a structure of structures to duplicate a structure created by an XML serialization.  Fundamentally the following structure is accurate and when I am READING the structure I can access the elements with array components as shown here.

What I can't do is figure out is the syntax to CREATE the array within the top level structure and then the array further into the structure.

```
        GetListResponse newone = new GetListResponse ();     // this works
        newone.marker = "";                                    // these work
        newone.count = 1;
        int x = 0;
        while (reader.Read())               // This works and is where the data is coming from 
        {
            newone.orderDetails[x] = new GetListResponseDetails();         // does NOT work!
            newone.orderDetails[x].order.orderId = Convert.ToInt32(reader[4]);
            newone.orderDetails[x].order.orderPlacedTime = Convert.ToUInt64(reader[0]);
            newone.orderDetails[x].order.orderValue = Convert.ToInt32(reader[3]) * Convert.ToDecimal(reader[5]);                
            newone.orderDetails[x].order.ItemDetails[0] = new GetListResponse OrderDetailsItemDetails()[];        // this DOESN'T WORK either
            newone.orderDetails[x].order.ItemDetails[0].Price = Convert.ToDecimal(reader[5]);
            newone.orderDetails[x].order.ItemDetails[0].filledQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(reader[3]);
            newone.orderDetails[x].order.ItemDetails[0].ItemNumber = 0;
           newone.orderDetails[x].order.ItemDetails[0].orderedQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(reader[3]);
            x++;
            }
```

***UPDATE Here is the class definition:

```
    public partial class GetListResponse {

    private int countField;

    private string markerField;

    private GetListResponseDetails[] orderDetailsField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public int count {
        get {
            return this.countField;
        }
        set {
            this.countField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string marker {
        get {
            return this.markerField;
        }
        set {
            this.markerField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("OrderDetails", IsNullable=false)]
    public GetListResponseDetails[] orderDetails {
        get {
            return this.orderDetailsField;
        }
        set {
            this.orderDetailsField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

and for item details:

```
   public partial class GetListResponserDetailsOrder {


    private string priceTypeField;


    private GetListResponseDetailsItemDetails[] ItemDetailsField;


        public GetListResponseDetailsItemDetails [] ItemDetails {
        get {
            return this.ItemDetailsField;
        }
        set {
            this.ItemDetailsField = value;
        }
    }


}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class GetListResponseOrderDetailsItemDetails {

    private long ItemNumberField;


    private decimal orderedQuantityField;

    private decimal filledQuantityField;

    private decimal PriceField;



}
```

Comment: `new GetListResponse Details();` What is this? There is no such syntax in C#.

Comment: Side note: just to clarify - as "structure of structures" you actually mean "class with list of other classes", not literally `struct Details`...

Comment: Can you show us what your GetListResponse structure/class looks like on the inside? That will help us understand what your issue is.

Comment: What I want to know is why Linq-to-Xml isn't being used here. This seems like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @Magus I don't know Linq very well.  How would you see me doing this in Link?  The data going into the structure is a flat "record" and the XML is all nested and stuff.

Comment: Linq-to-Xml is made specifically for parsing Xml in all it's complexity while preserving the structure. Look it up. You just need to instantiate an XDocument with a filename or the xml as a string.

Comment: @SchroedingersCat Thank you for the clarification on the class, and I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new GetListResponse Details();
```

Is not a valid constructor, but judging by your code it looks like the name of the orderDetails structure is Details so instead you should probably do:

```
new Details();
```

You do not need to specify the structure's name when you are initializing an object that is inside of a structure.

What you could do is change your GetListResponserDetailsOrder by making ItemDetails and ItemDetailsField into a list like so:

```
public partial class GetListResponserDetailsOrder
{
    private string priceTypeField;
    private List<GetListResponseDetailsItemDetails> ItemDetailsField;

    public List<GetListResponseDetailsItemDetails> ItemDetails
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ItemDetailsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.ItemDetailsField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then change your code so you can call the constructor like this:

```
GetListResponse newone = new GetListResponse ();
newone.marker = "";                                    
newone.count = 1;

for (int x = 0; reader.Read(); x++)
{
    newone.orderDetails[x] = new Details();
    newone.orderDetails[x].order.orderId = Convert.ToInt32(reader[4]);
    newone.orderDetails[x].order.orderPlacedTime = Convert.ToUInt64(reader[0]);
    newone.orderDetails[x].order.orderValue = Convert.ToInt32(reader[3]) * Convert.ToDecimal(reader[5]);                
    newone.orderDetails[x].order.ItemDetails = new List<GetListResponseDetailsItemDetails>();
    newone.orderDetails[x].order.ItemDetails.Add(new GetListResponseDetailsItemDetails());
    newone.orderDetails[x].order.ItemDetails[0].Price = Convert.ToDecimal(reader[5]);
    newone.orderDetails[x].order.ItemDetails[0].filledQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(reader[3]);
    newone.orderDetails[x].order.ItemDetails[0].ItemNumber = 0;
    newone.orderDetails[x].order.ItemDetails[0].orderedQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(reader[3]);
}
```

You will still be able to use the rest of the code as usual. You can call .Add(...) if you want to add more elements to the list later on, or .Remove(...) if you want to remove any elements.

Comment: If I do OrderDetailsItemDetails()[1] as you suggest I get an error: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type GetListResponseOrderDetailsOrderItemDetails'

Comment: Okay, could you show us in your question what the GetListResponse structure/class looks like? I would be able to give you a better answer if I could see how it is structured.

Comment: I thought about creating the objects as a list<>.  That is a good solution, but the risk of it NOT fitting perfectly with the stuff I don't control and the fact that I had learned and started the XmlWriter solution made that the final solution.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I wound up creating an XML document using XmlWriter and serializing it.  This solved the problem.  XmlWriter has a pretty quick learning curve so it seemed like the path of least resistance to generating the structure(s) I needed.  I am still curious how to instantiate the structures in c#, but the immediate need is satisfied.  Thanks for all the comments and suggestions.